# How is finiteness of solutions (zero-dimensionality) related to Krull's dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension

I have encountered a lot the concept of *zero-dimensional ideal*:

> Let $k$ be a field. An ideal $I\subseteq k[x_1,...,x_m]$ is said to be **zero-dimensional** if its zero set $Z(I)$ has a finite number of elements.

In [these](http://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/gdb/MA574/week11.pdf) notes, it is shown that an ideal is zero-dimensional if and only the dimension of $k[x_1,...,x_m] / I$ as a $k-$vector space is finite, and this is usually given as a definition. However, I'm concerned with the relation of this concept with Krull's dimension.

Krull's dimension is defined as the supremum of the lengths of all chains of prime ideals. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380687/zero-dimensional-ideals-in-polynomial-rings) post in MSE, $I$ is zero-dimensional if and only if its quotient ring $k[x_1,...,x_m] / I$ has Krull's dimension zero. My first question is:

> Is this the reason why the word *dimension* is involved in the **zero-dimensional** definition?

This is not a primarily opinion-based question. I'm just asking if the word *dimension* is involved in the definition is related to Krull's dimension in some way or not.

My second question is related with the second link I shared (the MSE post). It says that $k[x_1,...,x_m] / I$ has Krull's dimension zero if and only if $I$ is contained in finitely many prime ideals. However, what if $I$ is contained in at least two different prime ideals that have a containment relation? wouldn't the Krull's dimension of $k[x_1,...,x_m] / I$ be non-zero in this case?

Thanks a lot for your time, I really hope I can receive some help with these concepts.

Comment: @user26857 Of course I googled it, and I also searched in M.SE., as you can notice by the links I shared in the post. I decided to make a post by myself in order to gain a better intuition with the concept and make sure I really get what's going on. Fortunately, D_S was able to clarify the concept with a very nice geometric idea and he also answered the second question. AreaMan was very helpful too.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368448/zero-dimensional-ideals-and-finite-dimensional-algebras.

Comment: @user26857 Oh thanks! I wasn't expecting that, I just wanted to clarify that I did a search! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: the reason it is called a zero dimensional ideal is very intuitive: the zero set of such an ideal consists of finitely many isolated points in affine space.  One thinks of sparse points as being zero dimensional things, as opposed to curves, surfaces, hypersurfaces etc.

You *can* relate Krull dimension to the notion of zero dimensional ideal; I am not sure which use of the word dimension appears in the literature first, but both uses refer to the same geometric idea.  If $Z$ is a closed set in affine $n$ space, then then one has a notion of topological dimension of $Z$: the maximal number of inclusions of a chain of irreducible closed subsets of $Z$.  If $I$ is the ideal corresponding to $Z$, then the topological dimension of $Z$ turns out to be the Krull dimension of the ring $k[X_1, ... , X_n]/I$.  So as you mentioned, saying $I$ is zero dimensional is the same as saying the ring $k[X_1, ... , X_n]/I$ is zero dimensional, i.e. has no inclusions among prime ideals.

For your second question, it turns out that can't happen.  Let me do the case where $k$ is algebraically closed. If $I \subseteq \mathfrak p_1 \subsetneq \mathfrak p_2$, then $I$ will be contained in infinitely many maximal ideals.  Indeed, $Z(\mathfrak p_2)$ is strictly contained in $Z(\mathfrak p_1)$, so $Z(\mathfrak p_1)$ must be an infinite set (the $Z(\mathfrak p_i)$ are irreducible; in a topological space where one point sets are closed, each singleton set is irreducible, so any nonsingleton irreducible set must be infinite).  Hence $Z(I)$ is an infinite set, i.e. $I$ is not zero dimensional.  And, for each point $P$ in $Z(I)$, you will have $I$ contained in the ideal corresponding to $P$, and ideals corresponding to points are maximal.

For the case where $k$ is not algebraically closed, you actually need $I$ to satisfy the following property (usually given as the definition of zero dimensional ideal, but I am not sure if it the one you are using): an ideal $I$ of $R = k[X_1, ... , X_n]$ is **zero dimensional** if its zero set in $K^n$ for *every* field $K$ containing $k$ is finite.  In this case, let $K$ be an algebraic closure of $k$, then $S = K[X_1, ... , X_n]$ is integral over $R$.  The inclusion map $R \rightarrow S$ induces a ring homomorphism $\phi: R/I \rightarrow S/IS$.  The zero set of $I$ in $K^n$ is the same as the zero set of $IS$, so by the algebraically closed case, $\textrm{Dim } S/IS = 0$.  By the going up theorem, if $A$ is a subring of $B$ with $B$ integral over $A$, then $\textrm{Dim } A \leq \textrm{Dim } B$.  Since $S$ is integral over $R$, $S/IS$ is integral over the image of $\phi$, so $$\textrm{Dim } R/I \leq \textrm{Dim } \phi(R/I) \leq \textrm{Dim } S/IS = 0$$ Actually the first $\leq$ is an equality, because $\phi$ is injective (that is to say, $I = IS \cap R$), but that requires some commutative algebra machinery to prove quickly, and you don't need it here.

Comment: It's correct, of course, but there is a hidden application of Hilbert Nullstellensatz in your topological argument, when you say that $Z(P_2) $ is strictly contained in $Z(P_1)$. (To get the inclusion reversing bijection between primes and subvarieties...) I'm just nitpicking for the benefit of the reader. The intuition works, but there is some hard algebra in the background.

Comment: @D_S Thank you very much for your answer! the geometric idea you gave is clear and it helps me a lot in understanding the concept. Also, that little proof about the second question was extremely helpful! indeed, finitely many primes here imply only **one** prime, such an interesting thing! additionally, I'm not sure but... isn't it enough to prove it in the case that $k$ is algebraically closed? just by considering the algebraic closure of $k$...

Comment: You're welcome.  I should mention my proof doesn't work if $k$ is not algebraically closed, and you can see AreaMan's answer for the general case.  I don't think finitely many primes implies only one prime, though.

Comment: You are right, the algebraically closed case implies the general case!  I hadn't realized that, thank you.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: @D_S Well, there are a lot of things to study! but everything is clearer now! thanks a lot. By the way, when I said "only one prime", I was thinking in a different thing, of course, that is not necessarily true. Again, let me thank you for your answer, this has been extremely instructive!

Answer (score 3):

This is just adding to D_S's answer, saying the last paragraph algebraically just for clarity.

If $R$ is a domain, f.g. over a field $k$, which is not itself a field, then $R$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

I don't think you can avoid at least some tricky algebra here. (Which D_S slips into topological language - this is a really good habit, I think! But when you are learning the subject, like I am, it seems important to keep track of what is going on behind the scenes.)

Pf: By Noether normalization, there is a subring of $R$ which is isomorphic to $k[t]$, and $R$ is a finite module over this $k[t]$. Now the going up (or down?) theorem implies that for each prime $P$ of $k[t]$, there is a prime $Q$ of $R$ which restricts to $P$ ($Q \cap k[t] = P$). We can write down infinitely many maximal ideals of $k[t]$.

Comment: Dear AreaMan, this is a nice result:+1. You should make explicit that $t=(t_1,...,t_n)$ is actually an $n$-tuple of indeterminates and that $n=0$ implies that $R$ is a field.

Comment: It's not going-up, nor going-down, it's *lying-over*.